# Finding Broadcast Receivers that have been registered with registerReceiver()

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to find out if there is a broadcast receiver already set up to receive certain intents. (NOTE: These will be in different applications so I can't just keep track, I need a more dynamic solution.)

I already know that the packageManager.querybroadcastreceiver() will not find these.

Is there any other way that I might be able to do so?
Can I check to see if my Intent was received?

The last thing I want to do is to use a timer....

Answer (score 0):

If you control all those receivers yourself, or can force some behavior on them you can try using the [sendOrderedBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.os.Handler,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) method.
Note that you can define a "resultReceiver" which will be called after all the other receivers will be called.

So if you can force the other receivers to behave in a certain way, you can change the resultCode or even abort the broadcast when they get the intent, and that way in your resultReceiver you will be able to tell if others were called